# Can't install python module "pywhatkit"

Tags: python

So I was working on a automated whatsapp messenger and I tried to install the module known as "pywhatkit" but I am getting an error everytime.
The error trace is the following:

```
 ERROR: Exception: Traceback (most recent call last):   File
 "c:\users\पज\appdata\local\programs\python\python38\lib\site-packages\pip\_vendor\resolvelib\resolvers.py",
 line 171, in _merge_into_criterion
     crit = self.state.criteria[name] KeyError: 'pymsgbox'

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "c:\users\पज\appdata\local\programs\python\python38\lib\site-packages\pip\_internal\cli\base_command.py", line 189, in _main
    status = self.run(options, args)
  File "c:\users\पज\appdata\local\programs\python\python38\lib\site-packages\pip\_internal\cli\req_command.py", line 178, in wrapper
    return func(self, options, args)
  File "c:\users\पज\appdata\local\programs\python\python38\lib\site-packages\pip\_internal\commands\install.py", line 316, in run
    requirement_set = resolver.resolve(
  File "c:\users\पज\appdata\local\programs\python\python38\lib\site-packages\pip\_internal\resolution\resolvelib\resolver.py", line 121, in resolve
    self._result = resolver.resolve(
  File "c:\users\पज\appdata\local\programs\python\python38\lib\site-packages\pip\_vendor\resolvelib\resolvers.py", line 453, in resolve
    state = resolution.resolve(requirements, max_rounds=max_rounds)
  File "c:\users\पज\appdata\local\programs\python\python38\lib\site-packages\pip\_vendor\resolvelib\resolvers.py", line 318, in resolve
    name, crit = self._merge_into_criterion(r, parent=None)
  File "c:\users\पज\appdata\local\programs\python\python38\lib\site-packages\pip\_vendor\resolvelib\resolvers.py", line 173, in _merge_into_criterion
    crit = Criterion.from_requirement(self._p, requirement, parent)
  File "c:\users\पज\appdata\local\programs\python\python38\lib\site-packages\pip\_vendor\resolvelib\resolvers.py", line 82, in from_requirement
    if not cands:
  File "c:\users\पज\appdata\local\programs\python\python38\lib\site-packages\pip\_vendor\resolvelib\structs.py", line 124, in __bool__
    return bool(self._sequence)
  File "c:\users\पज\appdata\local\programs\python\python38\lib\site-packages\pip\_internal\resolution\resolvelib\found_candidates.py", line 143, in __bool__  
    return any(self)
  File "c:\users\पज\appdata\local\programs\python\python38\lib\site-packages\pip\_internal\resolution\resolvelib\found_candidates.py", line 38, in _iter_built
    candidate = func()
  File "c:\users\पज\appdata\local\programs\python\python38\lib\site-packages\pip\_internal\resolution\resolvelib\factory.py", line 167, in _make_candidate_from_link
    self._link_candidate_cache[link] = LinkCandidate(
  File "c:\users\पज\appdata\local\programs\python\python38\lib\site-packages\pip\_internal\resolution\resolvelib\candidates.py", line 300, in __init__        
    super().__init__(
  File "c:\users\पज\appdata\local\programs\python\python38\lib\site-packages\pip\_internal\resolution\resolvelib\candidates.py", line 144, in __init__        
    self.dist = self._prepare()
  File "c:\users\पज\appdata\local\programs\python\python38\lib\site-packages\pip\_internal\resolution\resolvelib\candidates.py", line 226, in _prepare        
    dist = self._prepare_distribution()
  File "c:\users\पज\appdata\local\programs\python\python38\lib\site-packages\pip\_internal\resolution\resolvelib\candidates.py", line 311, in _prepare_distribution
    return self._factory.preparer.prepare_linked_requirement(
  File "c:\users\पज\appdata\local\programs\python\python38\lib\site-packages\pip\_internal\operations\prepare.py", line 457, in prepare_linked_requirement    
    return self._prepare_linked_requirement(req, parallel_builds)
  File "c:\users\पज\appdata\local\programs\python\python38\lib\site-packages\pip\_internal\operations\prepare.py", line 500, in _prepare_linked_requirement   
    dist = _get_prepared_distribution(
  File "c:\users\पज\appdata\local\programs\python\python38\lib\site-packages\pip\_internal\operations\prepare.py", line 66, in _get_prepared_distribution     
    abstract_dist.prepare_distribution_metadata(finder, build_isolation)
  File "c:\users\पज\appdata\local\programs\python\python38\lib\site-packages\pip\_internal\distributions\sdist.py", line 39, in prepare_distribution_metadata 
    self._setup_isolation(finder)
  File "c:\users\पज\appdata\local\programs\python\python38\lib\site-packages\pip\_internal\distributions\sdist.py", line 66, in _setup_isolation
    self.req.build_env = BuildEnvironment()
  File "c:\users\पज\appdata\local\programs\python\python38\lib\site-packages\pip\_internal\build_env.py", line 83, in __init__
    fp.write(textwrap.dedent(
  File "c:\users\पज\appdata\local\programs\python\python38\lib\encodings\cp1252.py", line 19, in encode
    return codecs.charmap_encode(input,self.errors,encoding_table)[0]
UnicodeEncodeError: 'charmap' codec can't encode characters in position 148-149: character maps to <undefined>
```

Comment: Could you tell us how are you trying to install `pywhatkit`?

Answer (score 3):

`pip install pywhatkit`
If this doesn't work use
`pip install pipwin`
And then
`pipwin install pywhatkit`
If it is installed and giving error try
`pip install pywhatkit --upgrade`

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem. I used a lot of tricks but finally got my solution. I didn't add my python scripts directory in the path variable. `C:\Users\Computer\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python310\Scripts`. When I added this path to the path variable. Then **pywhatkit** was running on my machine. Note: I had recently reset my computer and gave it windows 10 pro!